# $wpdb returns wrong results with SELECT query

Tags: wordpress

I want to select my post_type from database with $wpdb->get_results but I receive wrong results compared to SQL query which runs from phpMyAdmin.

This is my $wpdb query:

```
$new_query = "SELECT `ID`, `post_title`, `post_date` FROM wp_posts WHERE `post_type`='inventory' AND `post_title` LIKE '"."%".$query."%'";    
    $inventories = $wpdb->get_results($new_query , ARRAY_N);
```

And this is SQL query:

```
SELECT `ID`,`post_title`,`post_date` FROM wp_posts  WHERE `post_type`='inventory' AND `post_title` LIKE "%zoom%";
```

SQL query that runs through phpmyadmin returns 6 results while $wpdb returns zero.
$wpdb can't find much that can find simple SQL query.

My function is not completed yet but it works with selecting all items:
I'll post hole function. This is raw code but it works.

```
function get_inventories_callback(){
    
    global $wpdb;
    $query = $_POST['query'];
    
    $cut_inventories = array();
    
    $i = 0;
    
    if ($query == "") {
    $inventories = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID, post_title, post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='inventory' AND post_status='publish'", ARRAY_N);
      }  else {
    $new_query = "SELECT `ID`, `post_title`, `post_date` FROM wp_posts WHERE `post_type`='inventory' AND `post_title` LIKE '"."%".$query."%'";    
    $inventories = $wpdb->get_results($new_query , ARRAY_N);      
      } 
    $page_num  = intval($_POST['page_num']);
    
    
    for($i = $page_num*25; $i < $page_num*25 + 25; $i++) {
            
    $url = wp_nonce_url(
    add_query_arg(
        array(
            'action' => 'trash',
            'post' => $inventories[$i][0],
        ),
        site_url( 'wp-admin/post.php' )
    ),
    'trash' . $inventories[$i][0], 
    '_wpnonce' 
);
        array_push($inventories[$i], $url);
        array_push($cut_inventories, $inventories[$i]); 
    }

    $ready_inventories  = array($cut_inventories, count($inventories));
    echo json_encode($ready_inventories);
        
    wp_die();
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Post your code after this line `$inventories =`

Comment: I have posted whole function. Thank you.

Comment: what is the value of `$page_num`?

Comment: $page_num  value is the number of page and it's passed through POST parameter from javascript AJAX function. It's part  of pagination which is not  completed yet. 
Well thank you, i found the problem it was because of $page_num.
$page_num was defined in javascript and has value of 2. When i do search results was returned, but then i'm writ pointed absent index and where value is equal null.

Comment: $page_num  value is the number of page and it's passed through POST parameter from javascript AJAX function. It's part  of pagination which is not  completed yet. 
Well thank you, i found the problem it was because of $page_num and for loop.
$page_num was defined in javascript and has value of 2. 
When i do search results was returned, and was in $inventories array, but when there too few results and page_num is bigger then zero i'm accesing index of array where value is absent and equal null. That's why i received array full of null's in ajax response.
Thank you.